# Disabling controls using JS

Tags: javascript, css, .net, html

I am kinda confused on a part of my code for a little side project I'm doing, I am trying to enter data entry on my inputs and select options and save it to a variable for the image/patient using the fields given (any of the dropdown options and gender options etc) and save it to a variable or something to use later.

The system is used to input a patients data with images corresponding to this (female patient, male patient and unknown patient), the type of injury that the patient has been inflicted with and store the data the user inputs in the dropdown menu's as follows:

Once the data has been written by the user, the AP button is pressed and the corresponding photo is fetched depending on what sex was selected and the bed is displayed as being occupied, and this goes with all the beddings.

I need to find a way to also disable the data entry options displayed above if the selected image is blank (empty bed).

(link to the jsfiddle is in comments below)

Comment: It's useful if you can create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's also helpful if you tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: @ktilcu I think I corrected the question to be a little more specific and a link added for the code I am talking about. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: OK! It looks like you don't have anything for 'btnAdmit_onClick()'. I would imagine thats where you would need to put this logic right? When someone clicks 'admit' we need to do a list of things. What would those be?

Comment: I also made this for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/nb5peq8u/ It looks like there are some HTML errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i give comment for easy understanding

```js
var imgProp = {
  'padding': '3px',
  'backgroundColor': '#666699',
  'borderSize': '1ps',
  'borderStyle': 'solid',
  'borderColor': '#000000'
};

// check selected and hide or show selectiondata
function checkSelected() {
  var allimgs = document.getElementById('multibeds').getElementsByTagName('img');
  var nrallimgs = allimgs.length;
  var selected = false
  for(i=0; i<nrallimgs; i++) {
    if (allimgs[i].getAttribute('class') == 'selected') {
      selected = true
    }
  }
  var selectiondata = document.getElementById('selectiondata');
  if (!selected) {
    selectiondata.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    selectiondata.style.display = 'block'
  }
}

function highlightImg() {
  var allimgs = document.getElementById('multibeds').getElementsByTagName('img');
  var nrallimgs = allimgs.length;
  for(i=0; i<nrallimgs; i++) {
    allimgs[i].onclick=function() {
      if(this.style.borderStyle == imgProp.borderStyle) {
        this.style.padding = 'auto';
        this.style.background = 'none';
        this.style.border = 'none';
        this.setAttribute('class', ''); // remove class for notice selected
      }
      else {
        this.style.padding = imgProp.padding;
        this.style.backgroundColor = imgProp.backgroundColor;
        this.style.borderSize = imgProp.borderSize;
        this.style.borderStyle = imgProp.borderStyle;
        this.style.borderColor = imgProp.borderColor;
        this.setAttribute('class', 'selected'); //add class for notice selected
      }
      checkSelected()
    }
  }
} 
highlightImg();
checkSelected();
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
tr, td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:white">NHS Ward Bed Booking System</h1>
    <p style="text-align:center;color:black">Click on one of the beds to select and fill in the value to place a patient/edit a patient.</p>
    <div id="multibeds">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty1" src="BedLEmpty.png" alt="Bed 1" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty3" src="BedLEmpty.png" alt="Bed 3" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty5" src="BedLEmpty.png" alt="Bed 5" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 5" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty7" src="BedLEmpty.png" alt="Bed 7" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 7" /></td>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty2" src="BedREmpty.png" alt="Bed 1" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 1" /></td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty4" src="BedREmpty.png" alt="Bed 3" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 3" /></td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty6" src="BedREmpty.png" alt="Bed 5" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 5" /></td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <td><img id="BedLEmpty8" src="BedREmpty.png" alt="Bed 7" width="100" height="75" border="1" onclick="" title="Patient Bed 7" /></td>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="selectiondata" align="center">
        <input id="btnAdmit" type="button" value="Admit patient" style="color:red" bgcolor="#00e6e6" onclick="btnAdmit_onClick()" />
        <input id="btnDischarge" type="button" value="Discharge patient" style="color:red" bgcolor="#00e6e6" onclick="btnDischarge_onClick()" />
        <select id="btnSelect">
            <option id="LocUnknown" value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
            <option id="LocHead" value="Head">Head</option>
            <option id="LocRightArm" value="Right Arm">Right Arm</option>
            <option id="LocLeftArm" value="LeftArm">Left Arm</option>
            <option id="LocChest" value="Chest">Chest</option>
            <option id="LocAbdo" value="Abdomen">Abdomen</option>
            <option id="LocLeftLeg" value="LeftLeg">Left Leg</option>
            <option id="LocRightLeg" value="RightLeg">Right Leg</option>
        </select>
        <select id="btnGender">
            <option id="GenUnknown" value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
            <option id="GenMale" value="Male">Male</option>
            <option id="GenFemale" value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input id="txtForename" type="text" value="Forename" />
        <input id="txtLastname" type="text" value="Firstname" />
    </div>
```